# tf.global_variables_initializer() does not work

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

Hello Tensorflow users/developers,

Even though I call initializer function, reporter tells me that none of my variable is initialized. I created them using **tf.get_variable()**. Here is where my session and graph objects are created:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Store all scores (each score is a loss-per-episode)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    all_scores, scores = [], []
    # Build common tensors used throughout entire session
    nn.build(seq_len)
    # Generate inference and loss models
    [loss, train_op] = nn.generate_models()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        try:
            st = time.time()
            # Initialize all variables (Note that! not operation tensors; but variable tensors)
            print('Initializing variables...')
            sess.run(init)
            print('Training starts...')
            for e, (input_, target) in sample_generator:
                feed_dict = nn.prepare_dict(input_, target)
                # Run one step of the model.  The return values are the activations
                # from the `train_op` (which is discarded) and the `loss` Op.
                x = sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables(tf.global_variables()))
                print(x)
                _, score = sess.run([train_op, loss],
                                    feed_dict=feed_dict)
                all_scores.append(score)
                scores.append(score)
                # Asses your predictions against target
                if e > 0 and not (e%100):
                    print('Episode %05d: %.6f' % (e, np.mean(scores).tolist()[0]))
                    scores.clear()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Elapsed time: %ld' % (time.time()-st))
            pass
```

I've called this method for millions of times before, and it had worked perfectly; but right now it is leaving me in the lurch. What do you think the cause might be? Any suggestion would really be appreciated.

P.S. I tried calling **tf.local_variables_initializer()** too; though reporter told me that you don't have any local at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like variables get defined after the `init` op is created. It won't include those initializers; you may just need to move it a few lines down.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.

Well I've figured it out. I shouldn't have executed the following assignment instruction before I build my model:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

*For anyone's information*: You may think that "**I'll execute and get the result of this operation called 'init' when I do so in a Session. So it doesn't matter where I do the assignment specified above**".

No! It is not true. Tensorflow decides on which variables to be initialized right after this assignment instruction is executed. Thus, call it after you build your entire model.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not exist I suspect you accidentally downgraded you Tensorflow version. 
Can you try tf.initialize_all_variables ?

If this does not work, can you post what version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. However this is my solution: just skip the init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

and just use :
sess = tf.Session
sess.run(init = tf.global_variables_initializer())